# Is it possible to disable iOS 3D touch on the embedded web view when using MSAL on Xamarin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We're using MSAL 2.6.2 on Xamarin.Forms. How do we disable IOS 3D touch on the embedded web view that MSAL uses for the login page. For example, when pressing and holding the link "Forgot password", the link pops out a browser, navigating to the change password url. This was reported as an issue on security pen test as it is possible to navigate away from the app and open the browser to show a fake login page where the url could start with login.microsoftonline.com.attacker.com and trick the user into submitting credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the gesture recognizer and set ShouuldReceiveTouch = NO.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/touch/touch-in-ios